# Can webpack 2 be configured to rerun jest tests when it recompiles in watch mode?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, jestjs, webpack-watch

I may have gone the wrong end of the stick here, but i want to re run my jest tests whenever the files recompile in webpacks watch mode.

I understand that jest cli has its own watch mode... but as part of my dev set up i wanted to rerun jest test when ever a file change.

Comment: jest already has its own fs watcher, so, just run [`jest --watch`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/cli.html)

Comment: would this mean id need to run 2 commands ?
`jest --watch` and `webpack --env=development --progress --colors`

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/webpack.html